# Bash: How can I replace what follows the equals sign consistently while skipping specific instances of key=value?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Within a configuration file I wish to consistently replace whatever follows the equals sign of a specific "key=xxxx" but skip all instances of "key=specificvalue". The value that follows the equal sign can be anything, except for the "specificvalue".

How can I do this within a bash shell script?

The file name is caConfig.txt. The line that I need to modify starts with commonName followed by whitespace and an equal sign. I want to replace the contents to the right with a passed argument $1.

```
commonName                      = supplied

commonName                      = supplied

commonName                      = walmart-sam.local.lan
```

I need to skip the first two lines, and modify whatever happens to be in the third line. I'd rather not count on the order of lines.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. It looks like awk might be the safer solution.

Comment: In your example, there are no cases where the second column would be "supplied"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say to use AWK:

```
awk -v a="$1" '/^commonName/ && $3 != "supplied" { $3=a } { print }' caConfig.txt
```

For any line starting with "commonName", swaps the third column for `$1` if the original value isn't "supplied".

Instead of `{ print }` to print every line, you can just put `1`:

```
awk -v a="$1" '/^commonName/ && $3 != "supplied" { $3 = a } 1' caConfig.txt
```

If you want to modify the file, you can either use indirection:

```
awk 'commands' > tmp && mv tmp caConfig.txt
```

or if you have a version of gawk >= 4.1.0, you can use the inplace module:

```
awk -i inplace 'commands' caConfig.txt
```

Comment: Tom, how would you modify this so it skips any matching key where the value equals "supplied"? I found two lines with commonName = supplied that I need to skip.

Comment: What is the 1 at the end?

Comment: Not there yet. Perhaps the FS needs to be modified to have white space and the equals?

Comment: Ok so the first pass I removed the -v. Now that I leave the -v, i can see that the output IS correct, but the file is unchanged. Is that what you expected? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is what I end up with when I use bash -x to see what is really going on: `+ cp truststore.ks /usr/java/apache-tomee-plus/conf/truststore.ks
+ awk -v a=acme '/^commonName/ && $3 != "supplied" { $3=a } 1' caConfig.txt`

Comment: hmm GNU Awk 3.1.6
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2007 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: It works using the first option. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Better to use awk for this:

```
awk -F '[= ]+' -v name="$k" -v value="$v" '$1==name{$2=value}1' file
```

Where `$k` represents key you want to replace and `$v` represents the value that want to update.

- This awk uses field separator as a regex `'[= ]+'` which means 1 or more of `=` or space.

Comment: I am going to try this since I do have two instances of this key that I need to skip: `awk -F '[= ]+' -v name="commonName" -v value="$1" '($1==name)&&($2!="supplied"){$2=value}1' caConfig.txt`

Comment: Hmm am I going to get into trouble since I have $1 having special meaning for awk and bash?

Comment: I found out after the fact that I needed to add a test, to skip instances of the key that have a value of "supplied". I made an attempt to do so but failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with sed

```
sed "s/^\([^ ]* *\)=.*/\1= $1/g"
```

which will work provided $1 does not contain any sed special characters.